# How can I add 1 to all integers in a dataset consiting integers and NAs (in R)?

Tags: r, addition, na

I have a dataset consisting of integers and NAs. I want to add 1 (+1) to all of the integers but not to the NAs. How can I do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would recommend you to add a reproducible example to show us what it is that you want.

Comment: `NA + 1` is `NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your df is named `df` and `var1` is the column you want to add 1 to:

```
df$var2 = df$var1 +1
```

where `var2` will be the column having the final result.

P.S. Adding 1 to NA still returns NA.